# NSPredicate not filtering correctly 

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to setup a NSPredicate to filter data.

I have a property of an entity called code that is in format like `55.534`.

I'm trying to fetch all data in a range, for example 50-60.
I have this but it doesn't work.

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.predicateFilterStart, self.predicateFilterEnd, nil]];
```

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get compile errors? Are the results returned incorrect?

Comment: Yes, its not returning anything.

Comment: how are you using this predicate?

Comment: With An FetchRequest, everything else is working fine.  Its obvious why this isn't working, I just don't know how to fix it.  The `code` are usually string with format like `55.234`

Comment: Your predicate seems to be okay. I made a small example project that shows it working http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/PredicateTest.zip

Comment: I tied that and get this error: `2011-08-13 13:49:12.405 Codes[16957:10d03] NSlog Array: code BETWEEN {"06", "07"}
2011-08-13 13:49:12.407 Codes[16957:10d03] -[NSCFString constantValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7464610
2011-08-13 13:49:12.409 Codes[16957:10d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString constantValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7464610'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your SQL syntax is wrong. Your predicate format should be

```
ANY code BETWEEN x AND y
```

Secondly, %@ formatter should receive NSString, while you're passing NSArray.

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@ AND %@", self.predicateFilterStart, self.predicateFilterEnd];
```

Comment: I don't think that would work though.  Cause will SDK know that 55.656 string is between string 50 and string 60?  And if the code is 64.345, don't I need to tell it to search for the first 2 index only?

Comment: Also got this crash `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ANY code BETWEEN %@ AND %@"'
***`

Comment: @Kashiv No - That's a valid predicate. See the example project.